# What does this notation in the Deep Learning book by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville mean?

Tags: backpropagation

When they first introduce the back propagation in an algorithm listing they write

> ... The next line computes $\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(j)}} = \sum_{i:j\in Pa(u^{(i)})}{\frac{\partial u^{(n)}}{\partial u^{(i)}}} \frac{\partial u^{(i)}}{\partial u^{(j)}}: ...$

What is the sum over? And how it is expressed here? I know $Pa(u^{(i)})$ is parents of the node $u^{(i)}$. But what is $i:j\in Pa(u^{(i)})$?

Comment: The sum is over all indices $i$ such that $j\in Pa(u^{(i)})$, i.e., all $i$'s such that $j$ is one of the parents of node $u^{(i)}$ or such that node $u^{(i)}$ is a child of $j$. Should it be $u{(j)}$ instead of $j$?

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. They omit the set parentheses. E.g. $\{i: ... \}$. The sum is over the set of $i$ such that... @Xi'an: Yes I agree, it should be $u^{(j)}$ instead of $j$.